# Scrapy rescrapes the start urls on stop and resume

Tags: python, scrapy

I use scrapy to scrape a list of urls from a file:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'some_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls=open(urls_file).read().splitlines()

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Everything works except if I stop and resume using a persistent queue, Scrapy rescrapes the entire list. my start and resume command:

```
scrapy crawl some_spider -s JOBDIR=state_dir
```

I see scrapy is actually writing to the state directory but `requests.seen` file stays at 0 KB. I've also tried using `BaseSpider` but the the result is the same

Comment: Can you try to crawl these urls using scrapy's `Request` module and do not stuff all the urls in `start_urls ?`

Comment: could you point me in the direction of how to put it all together?